# Separate a backreference from a number

Tags: r, regex, letters-and-numbers

Under R, I'm trying to separate letters and numbers in a string in order to add a 0 when the number is lower than 10 (one digit).

Example :

```
my_strings=c("GIR1", "GIR20", "GIR3ABC")
```

At the end, I want my strings = "GIR**0**1", "GIR20", "GIR**0**3ABC"

So I tried :

```
result=gsub("([A-Z]*)([1-9]{1})([A-Z]*)", "\\1Z\\2\\3",my_strings)
```

but I have 2 problems :

The first : it doesn't select strings with only one digit (it selects all), even though I specified `{1}`
and the second problem is that instead of the Z that I wrote in the replacement string, I want a `0`, but then, it becomes `\\10`. Does anyone knows how to separate the 1 and the 0 ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

`gsubfn` is like `gsub` except the replacement string can be a replacement function which inputs the match replacing it with the output of the function. The function can be specified in the ordinary way or in formula notation as we use here. As a consequence this one-liner can use a simple regex.

```
library (gsubfn)

gsubfn("\\d+", ~ if (nchar(x) == 1) paste0(0, x) else x, my_strings)
## [1] "GIR01"    "GIR20"    "GIR03ABC"
```

This also works

```
gsubfn("\\d+", ~ sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(x)), my_strings)
## [1] "GIR01"    "GIR20"    "GIR03ABC"
```

## Note

The input from the question

```
my_strings <- c("GIR1", "GIR20", "GIR3ABC")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gregexpr` to identify the numbers, and `regmatches` to extract and reassign back into the strings.

```r
my_strings <- c("GIR1", "GIR20", "GIR3ABC")
gre <- gregexpr("\\d+", my_strings)

regmatches(my_strings, gre)
# [[1]]
# [1] "1"
# [[2]]
# [1] "20"
# [[3]]
# [1] "3"
regmatches(my_strings, gre) <- sprintf("%02d", as.integer(unlist(regmatches(my_strings, gre))))
my_strings
# [1] "GIR01"    "GIR20"    "GIR03ABC"
```

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly, but I might use yours very soon, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

We can first extract the integers in your strings, pad it with zero, then replace the original integers with the one padded with zero.

```r
library(stringr)

my_strings=c("GIR1", "GIR20", "GIR3ABC")

str_replace(my_strings, "\\d+", str_pad(gsub("[^0-9]", "", my_strings), 2, pad = "0"))
#> [1] "GIR01"    "GIR20"    "GIR03ABC"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```r
gsub("(?<!\\d)([1-9])(?!\\d)", "0\\1",my_strings, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q6MnZb/1) and the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/ZfuqXL):

```r
my_strings=c("GIR1", "GIR20", "GIR3ABC")
gsub("(?<!\\d)([1-9])(?!\\d)", "0\\1",my_strings, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "GIR01"    "GIR20"    "GIR03ABC"
```

The `(?<!\d)([1-9])(?!\d)` regex matches

- `(?<!\d)` - a location not immediately preceded with a digit
- `([1-9])` - Group 1 (`\1`): a digit from `1` to `9`
- `(?!\d)` - a location not immediately followed with a digit.

Note the use of `perl=TRUE` since the regex contains lookarounds that are not supported by the native base R TRE regex engine.

Comment: Ouhaow, I'm very impressed, thank you !!!